# how can I implement a section recyclerview

Tags: android

I'm new to android and i'm making an app and I want it to have a udemy like or playstore like UI but I don't know how to implement multiple sections i've seen  various web pages but i can't seem to get a hold to it can anybody help me please? point me in the right direction or an easy tutorial please, Thank you for your kind help

something like this:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5WRlb_NPDauO0zluiwbL6JXF8c1G6uVxJwd2I_6hXY87x7Mc6gcbN7KMFtCe75kM0z4=h310
where it has the section of  based on your searches, courses on sale, we recommend, etc

this is what i have:

**activity main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hasg_.myapplication.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**adapter.java**

```
package com.example.hasg_.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by hasg_ on 23/01/2017.
 */
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> mDataset) {
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTitle.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTitle;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTitle= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hasg_.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    @Override
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDataset=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            mDataset.add("New Title #"+i);


        }
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter= new MainAdapter(mDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'multiple sections'? If you mean multiple ListViews, you'll have to create a ListView for each data source you wish to use.

Comment: i edited my question :)

Comment: http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 2):

Inflate different XML files inside onCreateViewHolder() like this:

```
View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_0, parent, false);
            break;

        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_1, parent, false);
            break;

        case 2:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_2, parent, false);
            break;

        case 3:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_3, parent, false);
            break;

        case 4:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_4, parent, false);
           breal;

        default:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_0, parent, false);

    }
```

Then override getItemViewType():

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position); //data source 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example given on GitHub check this https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a separate `RecyclerView` in your layout for each data source you wish to represent. If their data differs (and it likely will), you'll need to create unique Adapters and item layout files for each. Make sure to give them different IDs, as well as configuring them all correctly in your `MainActivity`.

You can then lay them out as you wish in clearer sections in `activity main.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding and how build from scratch, Please refer below link

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html